# Processing a GET request followed by a PUT in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am attempting to write a Python script which will allow me to process a GET request followed by a PUT based on the data received back from that same GET request. I would also need to run through this process for several different "members" so I am sure I will need to set up a "for" loop. There is a particular field that I need to change for several different "members" but the surrounding data that these members return may be different every time. For example, a GET request I would normally process using a Python script may return something like this:

```
{
"member": {
    "id": 12233444,
    "code": null,
    "code2": null,
    "code3": null,
    "state": "active",
    "cost_quarter": null,
    "master_id": 818667,
    "timeout_period": 2000,
    "enable_for_change": true,
    "is_prohibited": false,
    "site_id": 5544,
}}
```

I would then like to take this data, change the value for "timeout_period", and submit a PUT request. Typically, in the past, I have used the requests library in Python to process a GET request but for something like this, I am left a little puzzled. If someone could help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: So the `PUT` request will be initiated by your script to another server?

Comment: Both the GET and PUT request will hit the same server. Basically, I need to process a GET request, modify the data that is returned from that request, and then make a PUT request to submit the changes.

Answer (score 0):

To make a PUT request to change the timeout period of the member with id `12233444` to 3000, you would do something like:

```
url = 'your_url/12233444'
updated_member = {
  "member": {
      "id": 12233444,
      "code": null,
      "code2": null,
      "code3": null,
      "state": "active",
      "cost_quarter": null,
      "master_id": 818667,
      "timeout_period": 3000,
      "enable_for_change": true,
      "is_prohibited": false,
      "site_id": 5544,
  }}
requests.put(url, data=updated_member)
```